# How to install SimpleJson Package for Python

Tags: python, simplejson

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson

I am just diving into the Python world and want to make a simple twitter application which requires the installation of simplejson but not sure how I can set it up and get it working..

I am on a Windows System

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I would recommend [EasyInstall](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows), a package management application for Python.

Once you've installed EasyInstall, you should be able to go to a command window and type:

```
easy_install simplejson
```

This may require putting easy_install.exe on your PATH first, I don't remember if the EasyInstall setup does this for  you (something like `C:\Python25\Scripts`).

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads only seems to work with python 2.5? I have 2.6 installed...workarounds?

Comment: It looks like it's included in Python 2.6.  But, many of us still have to use Python 2.5.  :-)

Answer (score 33):

Really simple way is:

```
pip install simplejson
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-pip` on Ubuntu if you don't already have it

Answer (score 16):

If you have Python 2.6 installed then you already have simplejson - just import `json`; it's the same thing.

Comment: I followed the easy_install simplejson instructions but still had no luck. (Am also trying to install a python twitter client.) So I opened the .py file that was referencing simplejson, changed it to json, and then that worked.  :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can import json as simplejson like this:

```
import json as simplejson
```

and keep backward compatibility.

Comment: Assuming the above comment is coming from the 'Late Answers' or 'First Posts' review queue, not realizing this is an answer, not a question...

Answer (score 4):

Download the source code, unzip it to and directory, and execute python setup.py install.

Comment: For Linux, download [simplejson-3.XX.X.tar.gz](https://pypi.org/project/simplejson/#files), `tar -xvzf simplejson-3.XX.X.tar.gz`.