# validating JSON from command line using `python -m jsontool` gives 'No JSON object could be decoded'

Tags: python, json, command-line

I have a `data.json` file that I'm validating through the command line using python's json.tool, but it keeps giving me back an error message:

```
$ python -m json.tool < data.json
No JSON object could be decoded
```

Here are the contents of `data.json`:

```
$ cat data.json
{ "fields": 
    [
        [ "first_name", null, {} ],
        [ "last_name", null, {} ],
        [ "addr1", null, {} ],
        [ "addr2", null, {} ],
        [ "city", null, {} ],
    ]
}
```

I don't have a problem with [single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18415636/1094541), nor is the file empty (obviously), so I'm not sure what's causing the problem here.

Comment: cat dr-operators-config.json | python -m json.tool

Comment: python -m json.tool... good to know it exists.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It was because of the trailing comma after the last nested list `[ "city", null, {} ]`. I accidentally left it in and [JSON doesn't allow them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201856/1094541).