# ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded reading from file

Tags: python, json, python-3.2

I'm trying to load a JSON document into my Python code. The document looks like this:

```
{
  "FH45 G34": {
    "surname": "Foo",
    "firstName": "Bar",
    "address": "1275 Real Street, FooBar",
    "postCode": "Foo Bar",
    "county": "FooBar"
  },
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to load the file with the following Python code:

```
with open("foobar.json", "r") as foo:
        bar = json.load(foo)
```

However I get the following error `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

What's wrong?

EDIT: I'm not able to use the SimpleJSON module as it's not available for Python 3.2, which I am stuck using. JSONLint also shows my JSON as being valid.

EDIT 2: The whole file is [here](http://hastebin.com/ejeyimolof)

EDIT 3: Somehow the problem fixed itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying better error message than "No JSON object could be decoded"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899506/displaying-better-error-message-than-no-json-object-could-be-decoded)

Comment: @ivanab I'm not able to use the SimpleJSON module as it's not available for Python 3.2, which I am stuck using.

Comment: Are you sure your json file is a valid json?

Comment: @ivanab According to JSONLint.

Comment: You are missing a comma after the "...Street, FooBar", so the json is not valid as stated...

Comment: Maybe you can try ujson too, it should be available for Python 3 as well.

Comment: @ivanab Unfortunately it's for Python 3.3 and above

Comment: @holroy, that was just an error with copying the json file onto stackoverflow. I'll correct.

Comment: I think you need use `with open("foobar.json", "r") as foo: bar = json.loads(foo.read())`

Comment: @KevinGuan Unfortunately I get the same error. `json.load` should just read the file itself and then convert.

Comment: Could you please provide the entire file, or simplify the file to a bare minimum and see if you the error continues to occur? And which library are you actually using?

Comment: Hmm...what about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899506/displaying-better-error-message-than-no-json-object-could-be-decoded) question?

Comment: @KevinGuan, that is the possible duplicate question... But it has a hint that if one of the lists has a trailing comma, it might produce such an error message. So we do need to see more of the file, and not just an excerpt

Comment: @KevinGuan I'm not able to use the SimpleJSON module as it's not available for Python 3.2, which I am stuck using.

Comment: @holroy, the whole file is [here](http://hastebin.com/ejeyimolof)

Comment: @PaulClavier Okay, sorry about that.

Comment: @KevinGuan No problem!

Comment: @PaulClavier Well, I've just download your file and tried `with open("foobar.json", "r") as foo: bar = json.loads(foo.read())`, It's working fine on Python 3.5. Maybe this issue is about Python 3.2?

Comment: @KevinGuan I'll talk to my teacher about it.

Comment: @PaulClavier Okay, good luck :)

Comment: @PaulClavier , go with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199126/reading-a-json-file-using-python

Comment: Works for me with python 3.5  (Oh, I see Kevin Guar beat me too this.  Well, I confirm his experiment.)

Answer (score 0):

When reading the file using Python 2.7, it transforms most lines into unicode strings, which suggests that maybe the following change could make a difference in your Python 3.2 world:

```
with open('foobar.json', encoding='utf-8') as foo:
        bar = json.load(foo)
        # or
        bar = json.loads(foo.read())
```

### Detect offending line

If the above doesn't work, you need to find offending json code. One way to do this is simply to remove half of the file and try again. If it still fails, then keep on removing half the file.

If it works, replace the file with the failing part, and start removing halfs again. After a few attempts, you'll be able to locate the offending part of the file, or whether you have a basic reading error of sorts.

To eliminate reading errors, you could try doing a `print('file: {}'.format(foo.read()))` in front of the `json.loads()` call, just to verify the read contents.

### Test json inline

Another test you can try to further eliminate error sources are to take one or a few entries insert into a string and check whether it's the file handling or json handling which gives you the error. Something similar to the following:

```
json_text= '''
{ "FH45 G34": 
  {
    "surname": "Foo", 
    "firstName": "Bar",
    "address": "1275 Real Street, FooBar", 
    "postCode": "Foo Bar", 
    "county": "FooBar"
  }
}'''

parsed = json.loads(json_text)
```

And you could also check if it fails due to the space in the key of the first entry. In other words remove the spaces from a failing entry, primarily in the lefthand side key values.

If these tests are OK, you have some issue with your file read.  If they fail, you have some issue with the json module.

Comment: Nope, still not working over in Python 3.2 land. I saved the file as UTF-8 in Notepad, set encoding to UTF-8 and UTF-8-SIG, and tried with only one entry, and I still get the same error.

Comment: @PaulClavier, try the inline tests as described in my update

Comment: @PaulClavier, I've tested with a freshly compiled Python 3.2.6, and can't generate the error. Which exact version of Python are you running, and under which operating system?

Comment: The inline tests pass

Comment: @PaulClavier, if inline test pass, you have some issue with the file reading. Have you tried reading the file, and just doing a print on each line?

Answer (score 0):

The following code has been tested and works flawlessly with the [`whole JSON file`](http://hastebin.com/ejeyimolof) as provided in your question.

**Working Example** — Tested with Python ***2.6.9*** and ***2.7.10*** and ***3.2.5*** and ***3.3.5*** and ***3.5.0***

```python
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as json_data:

    data = json.load(json_data)

    for key, value in data.items():
        print('''
key    {0}

    county       {1}
    surname      {2}
    postCode     {3}
    firstName    {4}
    address      {5}
'''.format(*[key,
             value['county'],
             value['surname'],
             value['postCode'],
             value['firstName'],
             value['address']]))
```

**Output**

```
key    VB95 JGL

    county       FooBar
    surname      Foo
    postCode     Foo Bar
    firstName    Bar
    address      1272 Real Street, FooBar


key    AH63 FIR

    county       FooBar
    surname      Foo
    postCode     Foo Bar
    firstName    Bar
    address      1275 Real Street, FooBar
```

Comment: I've already tried that and unfortunaately it didn't work either. `.load()` automatically reads the file for you anyway so it shouldn't matter. `.loads()` is better for when you're parsing say a response from a webpage.

Comment: @paul-clavier I've just edited and tested my code to reflect what you mentioned, and ran it on a fresh install of Python 3.2.5 and it works the sames as with all the other versions I have tested it with. It seems that your copy of the json library may be broken/corrupted, or possibly something is wrong with your Python installation.

Comment: @paul-clavier Can you provide the exact release version of Python 3.2 that you are using? 3.2.0 or 3.2.1 or 3.2.2 or 3.2.3 or 3.2.4 or 3.2.5 or 3.2.6 ? You can get your Python version with the following line `import sys; print('.'.join(map(str, sys.version_info[0:3])))`

Comment: @PaulClavier, Have you tried the last test I suggested of using `json.loads(multiline_text_variable)` to check whether it is your file loading which fails, or the actual json library failing?