# elasticsearch mapping no JSON object error

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I'm trying to load data to elasticsearch 5 using the python script csv2es.

argument passed to csv2es references a json file with the elasticsearch mappings. when loading the mappings file below:

```
{
"dynamic": "true",
"properties": {
    "username": {"type": “text”},
    "date": {"type": "date", "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"},
    "retweets": {"type": “integer”},
    "favourites": {"type": “integer”},
    "text": {"type": “text”},
    "geo": {"type": “keyword”},
    "mentions": {"type": “text”},
    "hashtags": {"type": “text”},
    "id": {"type": “keyword”},
    "permalink": {"type": “keyword”}
    }
}
```

this throws the following error:

```
Applying mapping from: csv2es_mappings.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/csv2es", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 664, in     __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 644, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 837, in     invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 464, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/csv2es.py", line 206, in cli
mapping = json.loads(f.read())
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

However when I load the following file the data load runs. I'm using `text` and `keyword` instead of `string` as per the guidance for ES5 mappings- when using `string` the fields are not picked up and indexed properly.

```
{
"dynamic": "true",
"properties": {
    "username": {"type": "string"},
    "date": {"type": "date", "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"},
    "retweets": {"type": "string"},
    "favourites": {"type": "string"},
    "text": {"type": "string"},
    "geo": {"type": "string"},
    "mentions": {"type": "string"},
    "hashtags": {"type": "string"},
    "id": {"type": "string"},
    "permalink": {"type": "string"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik, that error means your json data is invalid.
In `“text”`, thats surrounded by `“` [left double quotation mark](http://graphemica.com/%E2%80%9C) instead `"` [quotation mark](http://graphemica.com/%22).

Upgrade your python, so you can see readable error while decode json string or use `simplejson` library.

See this: [Displaying better error message than "No JSON object could be decoded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899506/displaying-better-error-message-than-no-json-object-could-be-decoded)