# # Error: ValueError: file c:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2017\bin\python27.zip\json\decoder.py line 382: No JSON object could be decoded #

Tags: python, json, maya

I can run this script on my laptop, but when I run this script on a PC an error comes up.

```
import platform ,os, sys, re, json
global job, seq, shot, curApp, jobPath, jobPathLin, jobPathMaya, jobPathNuke,jobPathOsx, jobPathScripts, jobPathWin, nukeOutPath

jFile = open('%s/config.json' % os.environ['FXPIPEPATH'])
jData = json.load(jFile)`enter code here`
jFile.close()
```

Here is the error:

> Error: ValueError: file c:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2017\bin\python27.zip\json\decoder.py line 382: No JSON object could be decoded

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show an example of the json file?

Comment: Are you sure you do have that `config.json` file on your pc?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question.  You could improve the question by telling us which line in your code is line 382. Could you ascertain that the JSON file is on the PC  as well as on the laptop, and that it is the same file? Please [edit] such details into your question. Good luck!

Comment: Looks like you have some issues with json file and you probably try with a simplejson please see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899506/displaying-better-error-message-than-no-json-object-could-be-decoded